# Is there a way to build a regex that lists a certain substring exactly once?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Is it possible to build a `regex` that only matches a string that lists unique substrings exactly once? For example, say I want a regular expression that lists a few **different** colors. If I define it as:

```
'Here are a few different colors: (\w+), (\w+) and (\w+)'
```

Then the following string will of course, match:

```
'Here are a few different colors: red, green and red'
```

My question is, is there a way to force the list of colors, `(\w+), (\w+) and (\w+)`, to contain exactly one of any color? E.g.,

```
'Here are a few different colors: red, green and red'  # No match because 'red' appears more than once

'Here are a few different colors: red, green and blue'  # Match because all colors appear exactly once
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(?!.*\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b)Here are a few different colors: (\w+), (\w+) and (\w+)$
```

Try this.See demo.A `negative lookahead` will make sure that a word is not repeated again.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/114#python

`(?!.*\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b)` states that there should not be a word `\b\w+\b` anywhere in the string which gets repeated `\b\1\b` anywhere else in the string.

Comment: @vks indeed this is what I was looking for... Thanks! Now all I need is to open another question on **why** it works ;)